# Unable to map from mongodb results to java custom object

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this type of records present inside my collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "537470dce4b067b395ba47f2"
    },
    "symbol": "CMC",
    "tvol": 76.97
}
```

While retrieving results , i am unable to map to to my custom object 
This is my client program

```
public class Data {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String textUri = "mongodb://admin:password1@ds043388.mongolab.com:43388/stocks";
            MongoURI uri = new MongoURI(textUri);
            Mongo m = new Mongo(uri);
            DB db = m.getDB("stocks");
            DBCollection table = db.getCollection("stock");
            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            Security sec = (Security) cursor.next();
            System.out.println(sec.getSymbol());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Security.java**

```
package com;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

public class Security extends BasicDBObject {

    public Security() {

    }

    private String symbol;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

}
```

This is the exception i am getting .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.Security
    at com.Data.main(Data.java:25)
```

Comment: What are you searching for ? seems you are searching stocks. and you use search as BasicDbObject and assign the results to Security ? How Security relates here ?

Comment: even though i used the same name stocks for my dto , it throws the exception .

Comment: What you mean "used the same name" ? - How did you insert records into   mongodb ?

Comment: name doesn't matter , i guess you are not aware of that .

Comment: class name as stocks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the driver what class to instantiate, try adding this line before you run your find():

```
table.setObjectClass(Security.class);
```

Your getters on your Security class aren't really complete here, you'd need to do something like this:

```
public String getSymbol() {
   return getString("symbol");
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer , thank you very much , i was struggling for this .

Answer (score 1):

When MongoDB Driver returns it return as BasicDBObject for an Object by default which is kind of Map.

if you want to retrive as your own Java POJO , you have to implement DbObject Interface

[Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-java-dbobject-to-perform-saves/)

You are extending BasicDBObject which is internally implementing DBObject , so you are fine in that context.

However you have explicitly tell to Mongo to return as Security as

```
collection.setObjectClass(Security.class);
```